# 404 errors not going to custom page

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Thanks in advance for replying.
Simple Azure ASP.net 4.5 web forms website.

I am handling custom errors in the Global.asax. Page missing works when the middle of the url is changed. However, if the end is changed. It says 404 error and when deployed to Azure, it states a single line "Resource missing"
I am thinking this is web server issue and if my huntch is correct, how do I
a) Fix this on the IIS express in VS 2013
b) Fix this when deployed to Azure Websites
Cheers, Thnx & All the best
KFC

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm kind of shooting in the dark here. Could you possibly post the `httpErrors` and `customErrors` nodes from your Web.config, and the error handling code you're using in Global.asax?

That said, Global.asax isn't a great place to be handling custom error pages. You can use the `httpErrors` node in your Web.config to have IIS (7+, Azure is fine) catch errors and redirect. This lets you catch errors from inside (e.g. application exceptions) *and* outside (e.g. request validation failures, missing static files) your application:-

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <clear />
  <error statusCode="400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error" />
  <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Forbidden" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error" />
</httpErrors>
```

Remove the `customErrors` node entirely. It is unnecessary.

I've put a [full working example of using httpErrors for custom error pages up on github](https://github.com/iaingalloway/ASP.NET-HttpErrors-Example). You can also [see it live on azure web sites](http://httperrors-example.azurewebsites.net/Home).

Comment: Hey Ian, Your solution looks promising, will implement it and mark your answer as check. Thnx